# UIButton sizing wrong with image and title inset

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

It does not seem like UIButton instrinsicSize and/or sizeToFit takes a title left edge inset into account, or something is messed up with my expectations.

To demonstrate, I have two Custom type buttons in a view, both with the title "Button".  I want to add an image to the button to the left of a title.

```
    var image = UIImage(named: "circledPlay")
    image = image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)

    self.button1.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.button1.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    self.button1.sizeToFit()

    self.button2.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.button2.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)
    self.button2.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    self.button2.sizeToFit()
```

The result is as follows:

[image: screen shot]

Note the second button is being truncated.

So my question would be if anybody has seen this before (and hopefully has a solution) or am I confused and this is behaving as expected (and hopefully knows the right way to do this)?

Comment: You can subclass UIButton and override intrinsicContentSize.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it says in the documentation, for `titleEdgeInsets`: "The button does not use this property to determine `intrinsicContentSize` and `sizeThatFits:`".
So, setting the titleEdgeInsets just moves the title label, but doesn't affect the size of the button. If you want the button to have more padding around the content, set the contentEdgeInsets as well. I don't think you need to call either `sizeToFit`, or `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` (but 'm not sure about that).

Comment: RTFM would seem to apply then, as I missed that.  I can't say that I think it makes much sense if the world of autolayout that would be considered a correct behavior, but it is what it is.  I guess I should open a Radar with as much. Thanks.

Comment: @vagrant, Actually, I think this make sense in the world of auto layout. Using these 2 properties allows you to adjust the padding around the content of the button and the placement of the title (and image) without having to set an explicit width for the button, so that it can still expand or contract appropriately when the length of the title changes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `contentEdgeInsets` and `titleEdgeInsets` to implement that.

```
button2.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button2.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
button2.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 10)
button2.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, -10)
button2.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
button2.sizeToFit()
```

[image: button result]